# Practical example of the Optimal Page Replacement Algorithm, with 4 Tiles

Tags: algorithm, memory, memory-management, operating-system

I'm doing some theoretical examples with different page replacement algorithms, in order to get a better understanding for when I actually write the code. I'm kind of confused about this example.

> Given below is a physical memory with 4 tiles (4 sections?). The following pages are visited one after the other:
>
> `R = 1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 5, 3, 6, 1, 4, 2, 3, 1, 4`
>
> Run  the optimal page replacement algorithm on R with 4 tiles.

I know that  when a page needs to be swapped in, the operating system swaps out the page whose next use will occur farthest in the future. In practice I'll have:

```
Time    1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14
Page    1 2 3 2 4 5 3 6 1 4  2  3  1  4
Tile 1  1 1 1
Tile 2    2 2
Tile 3      3
Tile 4
```

I'm not sure what happens at time 4 because we get page `2`, but thats already present in the memory. Normally, if it was another number like `6`, then it would go in `Tile 4` but I'm lost in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At time `t=4`, page 2 is already present, so there is no need to do anything. You can just skip it and move to the next time interval.

If there was a another number like `6`, if there is a free slot available, you move it there, or else find the page that won't be used for the longest duration in the future and swap it.

Comment: So at t=4, 2 is not added and we stay at 123 until t=5 where we add 4 and have 1234?

Comment: @SkiMask Yes, exactly.